# Root privileges can be restored after setuid(1000) in musl libc

Tags: linux, security, setuid

`musl libc` allows you to change `uid` to `root` even after supposedly dropping permissions with `setuid(1000)`. I am not able to reproduce the problem with `glibc`.

Code:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    uid_t r, e, s;

    getresuid(&r, &e, &s);
    printf("%d %d %d\n", r, e, s);

    if (setuid(1000) != 0)
        puts("setuid(1000) failed");
    else
        puts("setuid(1000) succeded");

    getresuid(&r, &e, &s);
    printf("%d %d %d\n", r, e, s);

    if (setuid(0) != 0)
        puts("setuid(0) failed");
    else
        puts("setuid(0) succeded");

    getresuid(&r, &e, &s);
    printf("%d %d %d\n", r, e, s);

    return 0;
}
```

which, after compiling with `gcc -o setuidtest setuidtest.c`, produces the following output when running as root

```
0 0 0
setuid(1000) succeded
1000 1000 1000
setuid(0) succeded
0 0 0
```

I am running [Void Linux](https://voidlinux.org) with kernel version `4.18_1` and musl version `1.1.20_2`, glibc version `2.28_3`

Where does this problem come from? Is it my kernel, musl libc or is my testing code just incorrect?
Is this problem reproducible by other people?

## strace output (musl unpriviledged)

```
$ strace ./setuidtest (unpriviledged)
execve("./setuidtest", ["./setuidtest"], 0x7ffdd15f69e0 /* 24 vars */) = 0
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f538925cb28) = 0
set_tid_address(0x7f538925cb68)         = 6299
mprotect(0x7f5389259000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x55e9c5e75000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
getresuid([1000], [1000], [1000])       = 0
ioctl(1, TIOCGWINSZ, 0x7ffd2faf3160)    = -1 ENOTTY (Not a tty)
writev(1, [{iov_base="1000 1000 1000", iov_len=14}, {iov_base="\n", iov_len=1}], 21000 1000 1000
) = 15
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, ~[RTMIN RT_1 RT_2], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, ~[], NULL, 8) = 0
setuid(1000)                            = 0
futex(0x7f538925cfd8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
getresuid([1000], [1000], [1000])       = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, ~[RTMIN RT_1 RT_2], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, ~[], NULL, 8) = 0
setuid(0)                               = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
futex(0x7f538925cfd8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
getresuid([1000], [1000], [1000])       = 0
writev(1, [{iov_base="setuid(1000) succeded\n1000 1000 "..., iov_len=69}, {iov_base=NULL, iov_len=0}], 2setuid(1000) succeded
1000 1000 1000
setuid(0) failed
1000 1000 1000
) = 69
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

## strace output (musl as root)

```
# strace ./setuidtest (as root)
execve("./setuidtest", ["./setuidtest"], 0x7ffe19286eb0 /* 18 vars */) = 0
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f08b2619b28) = 0
set_tid_address(0x7f08b2619b68)         = 6409
mprotect(0x7f08b2616000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x561507eb4000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
getresuid([0], [0], [0])                = 0
ioctl(1, TIOCGWINSZ, 0x7fffb222bff0)    = -1 ENOTTY (Not a tty)
writev(1, [{iov_base="0 0 0", iov_len=5}, {iov_base="\n", iov_len=1}], 20 0 0
) = 6
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, ~[RTMIN RT_1 RT_2], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, ~[], NULL, 8) = 0
setuid(1000)                            = 0
futex(0x7f08b2619fd8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
getresuid([1000], [1000], [1000])       = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, ~[RTMIN RT_1 RT_2], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, ~[], NULL, 8) = 0
setuid(0)                               = 0
futex(0x7f08b2619fd8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
getresuid([0], [0], [0])                = 0
writev(1, [{iov_base="setuid(1000) succeded\n1000 1000 "..., iov_len=62}, {iov_base=NULL, iov_len=0}], 2setuid(1000) succeded
1000 1000 1000
setuid(0) succeded
0 0 0
) = 62
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

## strace output (glibc unprivileged)

```
$ strace ./setuidtest
execve("./setuidtest", ["./setuidtest"], 0x7fff673b2c20 /* 14 vars */) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x558b5fbb1000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/tls/x86_64/x86_64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/tls/x86_64/x86_64", 0x7ffc25da1650) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/tls/x86_64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/tls/x86_64", 0x7ffc25da1650) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/tls/x86_64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/tls/x86_64", 0x7ffc25da1650) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/tls/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/tls", 0x7ffc25da1650)    = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64/x86_64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/x86_64/x86_64", 0x7ffc25da1650) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/x86_64", 0x7ffc25da1650) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/x86_64", 0x7ffc25da1650) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\3604\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=18248368, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fbcd7093000
mmap(NULL, 3921920, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fbcd6ab1000
mprotect(0x7fbcd6c65000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fbcd6e65000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1b4000) = 0x7fbcd6e65000
mmap(0x7fbcd6e6b000, 14336, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fbcd6e6b000
close(3)                                = 0
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7fbcd7094500) = 0
mprotect(0x7fbcd6e65000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x558b5f5c0000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fbcd7095000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
getresuid([1000], [1000], [1000])       = 0
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFIFO|0600, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x558b5fbb1000
brk(0x558b5fbd2000)                     = 0x558b5fbd2000
setuid(1000)                            = 0
getresuid([1000], [1000], [1000])       = 0
setuid(0)                               = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
getresuid([1000], [1000], [1000])       = 0
write(1, "1000 1000 1000\nsetuid(1000) succ"..., 841000 1000 1000
setuid(1000) succeded
1000 1000 1000
setuid(0) failed
1000 1000 1000
) = 84
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

## strace output (glibc as root)

```
# strace ./setuidtest
execve("./test", ["./test"], 0x7ffc9176d3f0 /* 15 vars */) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x5653f4910000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/tls/x86_64/x86_64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/tls/x86_64/x86_64", 0x7ffe7d0c9550) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/tls/x86_64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/tls/x86_64", 0x7ffe7d0c9550) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/tls/x86_64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/tls/x86_64", 0x7ffe7d0c9550) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/tls/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/tls", 0x7ffe7d0c9550)    = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64/x86_64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/x86_64/x86_64", 0x7ffe7d0c9550) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/x86_64", 0x7ffe7d0c9550) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/x86_64", 0x7ffe7d0c9550) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\3604\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=18248368, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fb18f5af000
mmap(NULL, 3921920, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fb18efcd000
mprotect(0x7fb18f181000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fb18f381000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1b4000) = 0x7fb18f381000
mmap(0x7fb18f387000, 14336, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fb18f387000
close(3)                                = 0
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7fb18f5b0500) = 0
mprotect(0x7fb18f381000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x5653f40df000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fb18f5b1000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
getresuid([0], [0], [0])                = 0
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFIFO|0600, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x5653f4910000
brk(0x5653f4931000)                     = 0x5653f4931000
setuid(1000)                            = 0
getresuid([1000], [1000], [1000])       = 0
setuid(0)                               = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
getresuid([1000], [1000], [1000])       = 0
write(1, "0 0 0\nsetuid(1000) succeded\n1000"..., 750 0 0
setuid(1000) succeded
1000 1000 1000
setuid(0) failed
1000 1000 1000
) = 75
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Comment: Are you asking, if this is intended? If you want to report this as a bug, this site is not the right place, you should rather contact the musl developers (see https://www.musl-libc.org/support.html for mailinglist or IRC). If you prefer to use a web-based bugtracker, it's probably also ok to report it to the Void developers on Github (https://github.com/voidlinux/void-packages/issues).

Comment: It would be interesting to see the actual system calls and their return values to see where the bug is. Can you run `strace` on both versions of your program and add the relevant lines (get|set*uid) to your question?

Comment: @crater2150 As far as I understand, this is not intended. I am looking to find whether this is reproducible by other users, and the cause of this problem - is it the kernel, musl, or is my program incorrect? I will edit the question to make this more clear.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I have added the `strace` output. There seems to be nothing unexpected and all of the syscalls match up.

Comment: Is that strace output the musl version or the glibc version?

Comment: It must be the kernel. I can't reproduce it on 4.15/x86_64.

Comment: Can you post the glibc strace too?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion guys. I have now also posted the glibc strace.

Comment: Thanks. Strace is going to break setuid programs when invoked by a non-root user, so the only things we can compare are the ones invoked by root.

Comment: Note: this is the kernel's responsibility, not the library. It must be this way, or an attack could be to switch the library.

Comment: I can't see it. So I am wonder if capabilities are involved: Normally when the euid or last uid becomes non-zero, then all capabilities are dropped. However if the SECBIT_KEEP_CAPS bit is set, the capabilities are not cleared.

Comment: I'd insert ` { int fd = open("/proc/self/status", O_RDONLY); dup2(fd,0); system("cat"); close(fd); }` in there too to get a look at the process's capabilities masks. I bet they've got to be involved since AFAIK pure POSIX is concerned your situation shouldn't be possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue did indeed not come from either the kernel or musl but capabilities. There turned out to be a difference between my two testing systems - `glibc` and `musl` - which made it seem like it had something to do with them.

The problem was actually caused by the [`pam_rundir.so` module](https://github.com/jjk-jacky/pam_rundir/tree/next) which set the `SECBIT_NO_SETUID_FIXUP` secure bit, which makes the kernel keep capabilities for the program after `setuid` (therefore allowing me to `setuid` back to `root`).